# Terminal-IDE: Is there a working wiki somewhere to discuss issues unique to this environment?

Tags: terminal, wiki

I'm trying to use the "[Terminal-IDE](http://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/)" development environment.

I think it's FANTASTIC from what I can see so far, but at the moment its promise is more than it delivers (to me at least) because I'm having trouble getting to / from the phone as discussed in the HELP literature.

The wiki link on that page is non-functional.

While I have specific issues that may appear to be more of a generic nature and may appear to belong on, say ServerFault or SuperUser, I think they're likely to be common to people using Terminal-IDE...

I'm going to post those issues here in AndroidEnthusiasts as so far this seems like the best place....

Thanks.

**BY THE WAY,** a new tag, **"Terminal-IDE"** should be created, but, while I have plenty of reputation in StackOverflow, et al, I haven't got that reputation HERE. Would someone PLEASE create this tag (and let me know!), so we Terminal-IDE users can find related questions and answers? **THANKS!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In communications with the coder who created Terminal-IDE, known only as Spartacus Rex, the Terminal-IDE community is fairly new and no one had yet created a community.

So, I did.

You can now find:

- [A Web Site](http://Terminal-IDE.com/) where there may one day be a wiki (help needed - **can YOU help set up a Wiki?**).
- [An email list](http://server2.terminal-ide.com/mailman/listinfo/terminal-ide) to join to ask and answer questions. This list has a
  searchable archive.
- [A new Blog-Site.](http://Terminal-IDE.com/RichardsRamblings.html)
- And, at least one new contribution of code to help user's out. It's
  called [Resolver](http://Terminal-IDE.com/RR_resolver.html).

Happy? Give it a thumb's up!

Comment: +1 Thank you. I started http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Android/Terminal_IDE . I hope you find that wiki page useful.